# swiperjs Creative Effect Parameters opacity syntax error

Tags: swiper.js

I am try to use swiperjs syntax parameters: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#creative-effect
and i am getting syntax error ',' expected. Here is my js code:

effect: 'creative',
creativeEffect: {
prev: {
// will set `translateZ(-400px)` on previous slides
translate: [0, 0, -400],
},
next: {
// Slide opacity
opacity?: number;
},
}

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're not passing the parameters as a javascript object

```
creativeEffect={{
          prev: {
            // will set `translateZ(-400px)` on previous slides
            translate: ["100%", 0, 0],
          },
          next: {
            // will set `translateX(100%)` on next slides
            translate: ["100%", 0, 0],
          },
        }}
```

Notice two curly braces.